# Finding or proving the image of a function with a Cartesian product domain

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, solution-verification

I needed some help in understanding how to determine the image of a function with a Cartesian product domain.

For example a question like this:

$$f: \mathbb{N}^+ \times \mathbb{N}^+ \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad f(a, b) = (a+b)/2 .$$

How would I find the image of this function, or, if given the image, prove that it is the image?

My confusion is due to the two different variables $a$ and $b.$ Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Just to be sure: you mean $a +\frac b2$ (which is what you wrote), and not $\frac{a+b}2$, right?

Comment: Sorry my bad I meant (a+b)/2

Comment: For total clarity, you should include what you mean by $N$.  Some authors intend $\Bbb N$ to represent the set of *positive* integers $\{1,2,3,\dots\}$ while other authors intend $\Bbb N$ to represent the *non-negative* integers $\{0,1,2,3,\dots\}$.  The final  answer will depend on that.

Comment: As for the meaning of the question, reworded without too many fancy words, it is asking "What are the possible numbers which can be expressed as half of the sum of two natural numbers?"

Answer (score 1):

One way, which is often how I approach such problems, is to consider what you get if you fix $a$ and then let $b$ vary, to get a partial image $I_a$. Then think about repeating for a different $a$, and so on. Then try to think about what the union 
$$\bigcup_{a}I_a$$
of all the partial images is.

---

Another approach is to realize that $$\{a+b\mid a,b \in \mathbb N\} = \{2,3,4,5,6,\ldots\}$$

Can you then see what halving each element then gives?

Comment: all positive rational numbers?

Comment: @Rufyi $\frac{1}{3}$ is a positive rational number.  Is $\frac{1}{3}$ able to be expressed as half of the sum of two naturals?

Comment: Consider the cases of $a+b$ being even or odd separately. If it is even, then $\frac{a+b}2$ is an integer; if it is odd then the result is halfway between two integers. You can’t get anything else because that covers all possibilities, right?

Comment: yea your right so would I say the image is y e N or y e N/2 such that y>=2?